Using NER to label big parts of text
I'm trying to process a CV-like text, more exactly to split it into parts by their meaning (Description, Contacts, Experience, Education, Certifications etc).
Would NER be suitable for this purpose (labeling the whole paragraph as ABOUT_ME for example)? As far as I know NER's main focus is to find words or maybe the combinations of words, would it work for big parts of text?
Also I've looked at Text Classification, but it seems to be used for whole-text classification, not it's parts.
Is there any "ready-to-go" instrument or this task is non-typical?

Have you considered using an LLM for that? This seems a suitable use case. Also – can you give more details about the data (CVs) you want to process. How many documents, how diverse, how structured?

@petezurich I thought about using LLM, but it seems to be not very cheap solution in both cases: 1. paying API subscription fee for usage of ChatGPT or similar 2. running open-source LLM on cloud hosted instance (LLM seem to require a lot of resources, so it may be even more expensive).
About the CV-s I'd like to process: I could not say how structured the data would be, because users should access this functionality on website (like "Upload your CV and data from it would be extracted into form"), so I just suppose that my solution should be generic and handle for example 90% cases.

Have you calculated the token cost more precisely for your document volume? API costs have decreased significantly during the last 1.5 years. I can imagine that you successfully can process your data with less expensive models like GPT-4o mini, Anthropics Haiku or Googles Gemini 1.5 Flash.

Another thing to consider is how precisely can you extract the raw text from PDFs (assuming this is the file format you want to offer users). It can be far from trivial to retrieve clean text. You might have to use a vision model anyways for flexible processing.

@petezurich Thanks for advice, I've checked those cheap models and they really do the job fine for a pretty good cost.
So I'm going use the LLM solution, but maybe try using some combination of NER, Rule-based matching and Text Classification for "fallback" solution.
